# mod_rewrite and redirect to the same domain with added parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a plenty of domains with A records set to the IP of my server.

Apache is processing all this domains with a single virtual host.

What I need is to redirect 'mydomain.com' to 'mydomain.com/?param=mydomain.com' with mod_rewrite, but I don't know how to do this.

I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule / /?param=%{SERVER_NAME}
```

with no result. I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem of eternal redirection by adding `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to redirect `example.com/` to `example.com/?param=example.com` you will need to use the R flag , try :

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?param=%{SERVER_NAME} [L,R]
```

And if you want to  internally redirect `example.com/` to `example.com/?param=example.com` try the following :

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?param=%{SERVER_NAME} [L]
```

Comment: It dropped an error "can't compile reg exp '^/?$'. I;ve removed '?' and I don't get an error now, but I also don't see any redirections in access.log.

Comment: And it has gone cyclic
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS